# Sign up modal limit

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have integrated a sign up modal on a bootstrap website and would like to limit the number of impressions to visitors seeing it twice per session instead of on every page and also hiding it once a visitor has subscribed. The modal appears after 5 seconds of opening a web-page and only closes once a user clicks the close button.

```js
//Modal
$(document).ready(function () {
//Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
$("#bkgOverlay").delay(5000).fadeIn(400);
//Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)
$("#delayedPopup").delay(6000).fadeIn(400);
//Hide dialogue and background when the user clicks the close button
$("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
    HideDialog();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
//Controls how the modal popup is closed with the close button
function HideDialog() {
    $("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
    $("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
}
```

```css
html {
    background-color: #333;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

/****Modal*****/
/*Default Modal Styles*/
/*   This is the background overlay   */
.backgroundOverlay {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0,
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #000000;
 opacity: .85;
 filter: alpha(opacity=85);
 -moz-opacity: .85;
 z-index: 101;
 display: none;
}
/*   This is the Popup Window   */
.delayedPopupWindow {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 480px;
 height: 310px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -260px;
 margin-top: -180px;
 background-color: #efefef;
 border: 2px solid #333;
 z-index: 102;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
/*   This is the closing button  */
#btnClose {
 width:100%;
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #BCBCBC;
}
/*   This is the closing button hover state  */
#btnClose:hover {
 color: #c90c12;
}
/*   This is the description headline and paragraph for the form   */
#delayedPopup > div.formDescription {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 44%;
 padding: 1% 3%;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #666;
 clear: left;
}
/*   This is the styling for the form's headline   */
#delayedPopup > div.formDescription h2 {
 color: #444444;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*MailChimp Signup Form*/

/*   This is the signup form body  */
#delayedPopup #mc_embed_signup {
 float: left;
 width: 47%;
 padding: 1%;
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #666;
 margin-left: 1%;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input {
 width: 95%;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs when they are being hovered with the mouse  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input:hover {
 border:solid 2px #97c1c0;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #AAAAAA;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs when they are focused  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input:focus {
 border:solid 2px #333;
 box-shadow: none;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form submit button  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe {
 width: 100%!important;
 height: 40px!important;
 margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
 background: #333;
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form submit button hover state  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
 background: #97c1c0;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow:none!important;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.delayedPopupWindow {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    height: 310px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -260px;
    margin-top: -180px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    z-index: 102;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
<body>
  <h2>This a demo page</h2>
<!---Sign Up Modal---->
  <div id="bkgOverlay" class="backgroundOverlay" style="display: block;"></div>
  <div id="delayedPopup" class="delayedPopupWindow" style="display: block;">
    <!-- This is the close button -->
    <a href="#" id="btnClose" title="Click here to close this deal box.">[ X ]</a>
    <!-- This is the left side of the popup for the description -->
    <div class="formDescription">
      <h2>Sign Up and <span style="color: #333; font-weight: bold;">Save!</span></h2>
      <p>Sign up today and be the first to know about our SPECIALS!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
        <div class="mc-field-group">
          <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name
            <span class="asterisk">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
          <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name
            <span class="asterisk">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
          <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address
            <span class="asterisk">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
        </div>

        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
          <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
          <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
          <input type="text" name="PLEASE INPUT THE MAILCHIMP CODE" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
          <input type="submit" value="Save Money!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End MailChimp Signup Form -->
  </div> <!---End of Sign Up Modal-->

    <!------JS----->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin by carhartl.

Check for cookie before showing the modal. If it's present, don't display it. If it's not, store a new cookie and display modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
    $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    $('#bkgOverlay').modal('show');
}
```

});